# Colour should stay white, but with hover it turns black, while it should stay white

Tags: html, css, web

So I want to create this hex where when I hover over it white text appears, which it does, but only at the ending of the animation. What I want it to do is even when I hover over it, it stays white, solution?

[Picture of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w98Kn.png)

As you can see up above is what I have done with the hex, it normally is a picture and after the picture two boxes should slide over it and reveal some standard text, while staying a button that I have another use for. Now when I hover over it, like I said in the intro, the text turns black and barely readable, while I specified in the css code that the colour should be white. Am I doing something wrong or did I overlook something?

```css
#hexGrid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.hex {
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  /* fix for jagged edges in FF on hover transition */
}

.hex::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 86.602%;
  /* =  100 / tan(60) * 1.5 */
}

.hexIn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 96%;
  padding-bottom: 110.851%;
  /* =  width / sin(60) */
  margin: 0 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  /* fix for jagged edges in FF on hover transition */
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
}

.hexIn * {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  /* fix for jagged edges in FF on hover transition */
}

.hexLink {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
  transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
}


/*** HEX CONTENT **********************************************************************/

.hex img {
  left: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
}

.hex h1,
.hex p {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 128, 0.8);
  font-weight: 300;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-out, opacity .3s ease-out;
  transition: transform .2s ease-out, opacity .3s ease-out;
}

.hex h1 {
  bottom: 50%;
  padding-top: 50%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}

.hex h1::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 45%;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.hex p {
  top: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}


/*** HOVER EFFECT  **********************************************************************/

.hexLink:hover h1,
.hexLink:focus h1,
.hexLink:hover p,
.hexLink:focus p {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}


/*** HEXAGON SIZING AND EVEN ROW INDENTATION *****************************************************************/

@media (min-width:1201px) {
  /* <- 5-4  hexagons per row */
  #hexGrid {
    padding-bottom: 4.4%
  }
  .hex {
    width: 20%;
    /* = 100 / 5 */
  }
  .hex:nth-child(9n+6) {
    /* first hexagon of even rows */
    margin-left: 10%;
    /* = width of .hex / 2  to indent even rows */
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width:901px) {
  /* <- 4-3  hexagons per row */
  #hexGrid {
    padding-bottom: 5.5%
  }
  .hex {
    width: 25%;
    /* = 100 / 4 */
  }
  .hex:nth-child(7n+5) {
    /* first hexagon of even rows */
    margin-left: 12.5%;
    /* = width of .hex / 2  to indent even rows */
  }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) and (min-width:601px) {
  /* <- 3-2  hexagons per row */
  #hexGrid {
    padding-bottom: 7.4%
  }
  .hex {
    width: 33.333%;
    /* = 100 / 3 */
  }
  .hex:nth-child(5n+4) {
    /* first hexagon of even rows */
    margin-left: 16.666%;
    /* = width of .hex / 2  to indent even rows */
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  /* <- 2-1  hexagons per row */
  #hexGrid {
    padding-bottom: 11.2%
  }
  .hex {
    width: 50%;
    /* = 100 / 3 */
  }
  .hex:nth-child(3n+3) {
    /* first hexagon of even rows */
    margin-left: 25%;
    /* = width of .hex / 2  to indent even rows */
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #hexGrid {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="hexGrid">
  <li class="hex">
    <div class="hexIn">
      <a class="hexLink" href="#">
        <img src="https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8461/8048823381_0fbc2d8efb.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <div class="hexIn">
      <a class="hexLink" href="#">
        <img src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4144/5053682635_b348b24698.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <div class="hexIn">
      <a class="hexLink" href="#">
        <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2827/10384422264_d9c7299146.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <div class="hexIn">
      <a class="hexLink" href="#">
        <img src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4144/5053682635_b348b24698.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <div class="hexIn">
      <a class="hexLink" href="#">
        <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2827/10384422264_d9c7299146.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are talking about. There is no hover effect that would make text tun white - ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anywhere where you've tried adding the color directly to the elements themselves. I can only see that you've added the color to their parent element.

Have you tried simply just adding

`color: white;` or `color: #fff;`

directly to

```
.hex h1,
.hex p {
   ...
}
```

???

Comment: I've added the colour to the text, you should be able to find it under .hexLink
But with this I did manage to find the answer, so thank you indirectly.

Comment: .hexLink is the class for the parent element. You have an `<a></a>` with an `h1` and `p` inside it. The class is on the link element, which is the parent element of the `h1` and `p`. So yes, you have applied the color to the text, and it should work like that. But I was asking if you had tried adding it direcly to the text elements, not the parent link element. But I am happy I could help in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You have in your current code:

```
a,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

Fiddling with your snippet, I found that removing the `color: inherit` fixes the issue, see demo below. So it seems this was overriding the desired `color: #fff`.

If you still need this property to be set on other anchor tags in your page, you can then keep the property and only exclude the `.hexLink` anchor tags from having it:

```
a:not(.hexLink),
a:not(.hexLink):hover,
a:not(.hexLink):focus,
a:not(.hexLink):active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

Demo

```css
#hexGrid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.hex {
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  /* fix for jagged edges in FF on hover transition */
}

.hex::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 86.602%;
  /* =  100 / tan(60) * 1.5 */
}

.hexIn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 96%;
  padding-bottom: 110.851%;
  /* =  width / sin(60) */
  margin: 0 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  /* fix for jagged edges in FF on hover transition */
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -60deg) skewY(30deg);
}

.hexIn * {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  /* fix for jagged edges in FF on hover transition */
}

.hexLink {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
  transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 60deg);
}


/*** HEX CONTENT **********************************************************************/

.hex img {
  left: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 0, 0deg);
}

.hex h1,
.hex p {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 128, 0.8);
  font-weight: 300;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-out, opacity .3s ease-out;
  transition: transform .2s ease-out, opacity .3s ease-out;
}

.hex h1 {
  bottom: 50%;
  padding-top: 50%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}

.hex h1::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 45%;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.hex p {
  top: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}

a:not(.hexLink),
a:not(.hexLink):hover,
a:not(.hexLink):focus,
a:not(.hexLink):active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}


/*** HOVER EFFECT  **********************************************************************/

.hexLink:hover h1,
.hexLink:focus h1,
.hexLink:hover p,
.hexLink:focus p {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}


/*** HEXAGON SIZING AND EVEN ROW INDENTATION *****************************************************************/

@media (min-width:1201px) {
  /* <- 5-4  hexagons per row */
  #hexGrid {
    padding-bottom: 4.4%
  }
  .hex {
    width: 20%;
    /* = 100 / 5 */
  }
  .hex:nth-child(9n+6) {
    /* first hexagon of even rows */
    margin-left: 10%;
    /* = width of .hex / 2  to indent even rows */
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width:901px) {
  /* <- 4-3  hexagons per row */
  #hexGrid {
    padding-bottom: 5.5%
  }
  .hex {
    width: 25%;
    /* = 100 / 4 */
  }
  .hex:nth-child(7n+5) {
    /* first hexagon of even rows */
    margin-left: 12.5%;
    /* = width of .hex / 2  to indent even rows */
  }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) and (min-width:601px) {
  /* <- 3-2  hexagons per row */
  #hexGrid {
    padding-bottom: 7.4%
  }
  .hex {
    width: 33.333%;
    /* = 100 / 3 */
  }
  .hex:nth-child(5n+4) {
    /* first hexagon of even rows */
    margin-left: 16.666%;
    /* = width of .hex / 2  to indent even rows */
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  /* <- 2-1  hexagons per row */
  #hexGrid {
    padding-bottom: 11.2%
  }
  .hex {
    width: 50%;
    /* = 100 / 3 */
  }
  .hex:nth-child(3n+3) {
    /* first hexagon of even rows */
    margin-left: 25%;
    /* = width of .hex / 2  to indent even rows */
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #hexGrid {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="hexGrid">
  <li class="hex">
    <div class="hexIn">
      <a class="hexLink" href="#">
        <img src="https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8461/8048823381_0fbc2d8efb.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <div class="hexIn">
      <a class="hexLink" href="#">
        <img src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4144/5053682635_b348b24698.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <div class="hexIn">
      <a class="hexLink" href="#">
        <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2827/10384422264_d9c7299146.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <div class="hexIn">
      <a class="hexLink" href="#">
        <img src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4144/5053682635_b348b24698.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="hex">
    <div class="hexIn">
      <a class="hexLink" href="#">
        <img src="https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2827/10384422264_d9c7299146.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
        <p>Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Even with that fix the colour stays dark, where I want it to be white (or at least a lighter grey) so either your and my program are different or I made a mistake elsewhere in the css.